# spawn casperjs ENOENT error on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, casperjs, spookyjs

I am trying to run a casper **scraper** on nodejs using SPOOKY. The **scraper** works fine when I run it on the localhost but gives the error below when I deploy the project on AWS elastic beanstalk server.

```
Error: spawn casperjs ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have tried setting `binPath: './node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs'"` and tried installing Casper globally but was unable to do it. I also added  `command: /^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'casperjs.cmd' : 'casperjs',` to the child but that did not work out either.

I have been searching this for more then a week but was unsuccessful.

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install globally `casperjs` - `npm i -g casperjs`

You can read more [here](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/issues/206)